# Why is my div #firstpage displaying on my div #lastpage when the div #firstpage is set to hide?

Tags: php, html

I have been working on this PHP and HTML code off and on for a week trying to figure out why my div id for my #firstpage is displaying on my div id #lastpage, when the div id for #firstpage is set to hide? The code is supposed to display the first page, when the user hit the "Select" button the first page should hide and the second page should be displayed. Once the second page is displayed, the user hits the "Select" button and the second page should be hidden and the last page should be displayed.

What is happening is on the last page, both the first page and the last page are being displayed.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$first = "";
if (isset($_POST[submit])){
$first = "hide";
}

$second = "";
if (isset($_POST[submit8])){
$second = "hide";

}
var_dump($first);
var_dump($second);
var_dump($first!="");
var_dump($second!="");

if (isset($_POST[submit9])){
}
?>

<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
<style>
#formState { width: 35%;}
#formCounty { width: 35%;}
    
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#aaa;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#333;background-color:#fff;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#fff;background-color:#f38630;}
.tg .tg-cly1{text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dependent-dropdown/1.4.9/js/dependent-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css">
<body>
<div id="firstpage">    
<form method='POST'>
    <h4>Hello and Welcome to our Players Looking for Teams to Play on!</h4>
    <h4>We have to ask a few questions</h4>
    
    <h6>Please select the State you would like to play in:</h6>
    <p>Select State
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Select" Style = "color:white; background-color:blue" required>        
</form>
</div>
<div id="secondpage">
<form method='POST'>
    <h4>Hello and Welcome to our Players Looking for Teams to Play on!</h4>
    <h4>Now, what county will you play out of?</h4>
    
    <h6>Please select the County you would like to play in:</h6>
    <input type="submit" name="submit8" value="Select" Style = "color:white; background-color:blue" required>
</form>
</div>  
<div id="lastpage">
<form method="POST">
    <h4>Hello and Welcome to our Players Looking for Teams to Play on!</h4>
    <h4>All Done!! This is how Captains will see your listing.</h4>
<input type="submit" name="submit9" value="Submit Listing" Style = "color:white; background-color:blue" required>
</form>
</div>

</body>
<?php
if($first!=""){
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#firstpage").hide(); 
$("#secondpage").show();
$("#lastpage").hide();
     </script>
<?php
}elseif($second!=""){
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#firstpage").hide(); 
$("#secondpage").hide();
$("#lastpage").show();
     </script>
<?php
}else{
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#firstpage").show();
$("#secondpage").hide();
$("#lastpage").hide();
</script>
<?php
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".chosen").chosen();
    </script>

</html>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to submit a form, what's the point of using JS to show or hide the divs? Why not just use a `switch()` to decide which page to display before you draw each one?

Comment: A while back I was searching for a method to display multiple forms on one page. I submitted this question to StackOverflow and continued on that path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688195/my-multi-form-pages-works-great-until-i-unset-a-variable-why.

Comment: @droopsnoot I made the adjustment to using switch(). Your suggestion worked perfectly.